# react router + express with webpack

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, react-router

I am working on a blog. I have an express server which has various APIs like /api/getpost , /api/newpost etc etc.

I have my react components and i am using react router 4 ,  my routes are /addpost /home etc. etc.

In my server.js i served my static files(bundel.js)

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/dist'));
```

then

```
app.get('*', function(res,req){
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'index.html'));
});
```

`localhost:3000/` loads homepage properly
`localhost:3000/home` also loads
`localhost:3000/api/getpost` fails !

i couldn't find solution of this after several hours of searching

EDIT : 
I am adding more details !

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route,Redirect} from 'react-router-dom';
<Router>
 <div>
  <Route exact path="/" component ={App}>
  <Route path="/home" component ={Home}>
 </div>
</Router>
```

and my server.js file

```js
var express  = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    var router = require('./router');
var User = require('./app/components/data');
var path = require('path');


const app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/dist'));

app.get('*', function(res,req){
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname ,'/dist/index.html'));
});

app.use('/api',router);

router.route('/getpost').get(function(req, res) {
   User.find(function(err,user) {
   if (err)
    res.send(err);
   res.json(user);
 });
});
```

error which i got in my app : 
Error: Network Error Stack trace: createError@localhost:3000/bundle.js:9088:15 handleError@localhost:3000/bundle.js:8935:14

Comment: What do you mean by "fails"? How does it fail?

Comment: it shows cannot get /api/getpost and in my app it gives network error

Comment: when i change
app.get('*', function(res,req){
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'index.html'));
}); 

to

app.get('/', function(res,req){
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'index.html'));
}); 

my api works well but then routing to /home gives cannot get /home

Comment: which network error? could you edit your answer and add such informations?

Comment: @enapupe
Error: Network Error
Stack trace:
createError@http://localhost:3000/bundle.js:9088:15
handleError@http://localhost:3000/bundle.js:8935:14

Comment: I think your order of routes declared in `server.js` could be causing an issue.  `/api/getpost` will never get hit because you have a catchall listed above it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving your api route above your `app.get(*, ...` route.  That route is catching every request, so when you hit `localhost:3000/api/getpost`, react-router tries to load in the component that matches `/api/getpost` and fails since you have not and do not want to define it.

Answer (score 0):

Your express file should be ordered correctly:-

Here is what you can try

```
var express  = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    var router = require('./router');
var User = require('./app/components/data');
var path = require('path');


const app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/dist'));

app.use('/api',router);

router.route('/getpost').get(function(req, res) {
   User.find(function(err,user) {
   if (err)
    res.send(err);
   res.json(user);
 });
});

app.get('*', function(res,req){
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname ,'/dist/index.html'));
});
```